# Ubuntu freezes at installation-dialog and at live-boot

Tags: installation, laptop, 32-bit

i´m quite new to ubuntu/linux, because i prefered using windows, yet.
Now i have a older notebook that runs very slow with windows xp and consumples a lot of battery.
So i choosed to use a more efficient operating system - ubuntu.

As a fan of the new interface of ubuntu i definitly was about to install 12.04 LTS.
Well.. my Notebook is to old for it because its 32bit CPU doesn´t support PAE.

So i tried to install:
10.04 LTS, 11.04, 12.04 Non-PAE, 12.04 via Network (mini.iso), xubuntu 12.04
Always i386-version

But always when i want to install, the dialog freezes, means i can´t click anywhere but the mouse is still moveable.
When i try to boot from stick and select live-boot it loads ubuntu and after a few seconds it looks like this:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=5BB06F365D867D6A!405&authkey=!AMB0D4NdNdeaOBk

Hardware information:
CPU: Pentium M 725, RAM: 512 MB, GPU: ATI Mobility Radeon 9700 (64MB), HDD: 80GB

Thanks for your awesome help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use ancient Ubuntu. Use modern Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead. Unity will not run on this revered veteran even if you manage to install it. I have Zenwalk Linux running on such machines OK.

Comment: I´m only able to use Ubuntu <12.04 because the newer versions all require a CPU that supports PAE, which the Pentium M doesn´t. Tried now about 20 different versions. Also Linux Mint doesn´t work. Time to reinstall windows....

Comment: Zenwalk. Arch. OpenSuse XFCE. Calculate Linux.